# svn change file name cause code association different storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I was used SVN to change file name, maybe by a wrong way. It works in my normal Xcode project, but when i build for a static library.It's code association before version file code, and my code association two different storyboard.Like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/517f9.png)

Comment: I don't undestand the last part. More generally, can you give more informations, code, errors ?

Comment: It's files associate with different version. And my code  had deleted but it was appeared in static library. I changed the storyboard and delete the button, but it crash ---*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<LeZhuoGameUserInfomationViewController 0x7fb1dbe3e7b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bindingUserButton.'---.I think it associate old code and file.

Comment: I found it was SVN caused.With error operation change file name.It cause code associate to different version storyboard. I extract my code file to new project to build it . It was succeed. But how to fix the error association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was because I changed the file case name. But the SVN  associate the old file.When I extract my code file to new project to build it . It was succeed.